# Branching statement issue (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, xifthen

I am using a branching statement in a `tikzpicture` as presented in the [Ti*k*Z & PGF Manual](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/pgf_CVS.pdf) (p. 634). Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,textwidth=8.5in,textheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzmath{
\a = 2;
if \a <= 5 then {
\draw (0,0) rectangle (\a,\a);
} else {
\draw (0,0) parabola (\a,\a);
};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Nevertheless, it does not work... What am I doing wrong?

I get the following error :

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Do you get errors? If so, which error messages exactly?

Comment: I answered by editing the post.

Comment: Do make sure that the manual you are using matches the version of the software you are using. I am not using that documentation, for example, because it does not match the version current in TeX Live 2015.

Comment: Did you read the pgfmanual (look at section 56.7 "Executing Code Outside the Parser", p.652, pgfmanul v3.0.0)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like this, though I'm not terribly familiar with this library:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzmath{
      \a = 2;
      if \a <= 5 then { let \b = rectangle; } else { let \b = parabola; };
    }
    \draw (0,0) \b (\a,\a);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can do the drawing within the parser if you protect it with `{...};`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzmath{
      \a = 6;
      if \a <= 5 then { let \b = rectangle; } else { let \b = parabola; };
      { \draw (0,0) \b (\a,\a); };
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or you can use similar protection to do the drawing within the conditional:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzmath{
      \a = 1;
      if \a <= 5 then { {\draw (0,0) rectangle (\a,\a);}; } else { {\draw (0,0) parabola (\a,\a);}; };
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As cfr points out the intended way of executing code outside `tikzmath` parser is to place it inside braces (followed by a semicolon). No braces are required around the condition though:

```
\tikzmath{
  \a = 2;
  if \a <= 5 then {
    { \draw (0,0) rectangle (\a,\a); };
  }   else {
    { \draw (0,0) parabola (\a,\a); };
  };
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes. They were a side-effect of my figuring things out by trial-and-error. I think I misread the `<>` in the manual for `{<>}`. Thanks.

Comment: I've removed them from my answer. Hope that was OK.